# 10.6 Details We noticed that the user is taken to Safari to sign in or register for an account, which provides a poor user experience

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store, google-plus

My app got rejected because of the following reason.

10.6 Details We noticed that the user is taken to Safari to sign in or register for an account, which provides a poor user experience.

**Next Steps**

Please revise your app to enable users to sign in or register an account in the app.

We recommend implementing the Safari View Controller API to display web content within your app. The Safari View Controller allows the display of a URL and inspection of the certificate from an embedded browser in an app so that customers can verify the webpage URL and SSL certificate to confirm they are entering their sign in credentials into a legitimate page.

Resources

For additional information on the Safari View Controller API, please see the webpage, [What’s New in Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Introduction/Introduction.html).

I am using Facebook and Google plus sign in. Is this because of Facebook or Google Plus sign in? Because if there is no Facebook/Google plus app installed on users device, it will launch Safari/default browser for Facebook/Google+ login page. My previous binary built was approved by apple and till now i haven't make any changes on signIn/register flow.

I am considering to implement what they recommended but cant get my head straight with, *Safari View Controller API to display web content within your app*. How to display Facebook/Google+ login page using Safari View controller? I am kind of stuck here. If anyone can share any bit of idea regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced with same problem, in my case app rejected because of google+ signin.
I implement new SDK , I uploaded new version and its successfully worked.
[Find link here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating)

Comment: Thanks @Meera, I will try using Google Sign-in.

Comment: @Meera Thanks, This answer is very useful for me :)

Comment: Hey @Meera, Do you know how to retrieve gender and DOB

Comment: Using Google signIn it is not possible but, i found one way may its work for you , get using REST api may be it is useful to you try this : [link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get#try-it)

Comment: I can't find the solution

Comment: New sdk also taking to safari browser for Google log in, how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem. It should allow for Google+ and Facebook signin. Just add this to your AppDelegate.swift file (or what ever you've named your UIApllicationDelegate subclass). Let me know how it works out for you.

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    //        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    let urlString = url.absoluteString as NSString
    let substring = urlString.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 2))
    print("FACEBOOKURL \(substring)")

    if substring == "fb" {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
    }else {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, options options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        let urlString = url.absoluteString as NSString
        let substring = urlString.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 2))
        print("FACEBOOKURL \(substring)")

        if substring == "fb" {
            return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
                openURL: url,
                sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]! as! String,
                annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
        }else {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]! as! String,
                annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `SFSafariViewController` and its `delegate` will be the best solution to open an external URL in the app. Same issue happened to me and I have used following code(in objective C) to resolve the issue and uploaded app successfully to the iTunes store.

Use Framework:

```
#import <SafariServices/SafariServices.h>
```

and then use this code:

```
-(void)openURLWithSafariController:(NSString*)strUrl
    {
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];

        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9.0)
        {
            if ([SFSafariViewController class] != nil)
            {
                SFSafariViewController *sfvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL];
                sfvc.delegate = self;
                [self presentViewController:sfvc animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
            else
            {
                if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL])
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[URL description]);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
        }
    }


    #pragma Safari View Controller Delegate

    - (void)safariViewControllerDidFinish:(nonnull SFSafariViewController *)controller
    {
        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

and then call this method:

```
[self openURLWithSafariController:@"Pass some valid URL which you have tried to open in external browser"];
```

Check the code and let me know if any query remains still with the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

[WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html)

[WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html) renders web content in a native view.

Use [WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html) and your "registration" and "password reset" pages will display within your app and not launch an external Safari view.

It looks pretty good if your website supports mobile browsers.